# Data modelling for "sequence" in xml Schema to OOP

Tags: xml, oop, uml, schema, sequence

Trying to find out how to data model the `sequence` element in an xml Schema to an Object Oriented (UML) but could not find any helpful documentation online.
I am using Capella Melody Advanced.

```
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="yyyyyyyy" type="zz:xxxx"/>
        <xs:element name="cccccc" type="zz:Ccccc" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>......</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
```

Comment: Read here: https://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/About-XMI/ Good luck

Comment: You would have to provide a more complete example for making your question meaningful. An XML sequence element can be used for different purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Comment: @GerdWagner Please check the edited question, I added an example.

Comment: @MFF: Unfortunately, your example code does not inidcate in which type definition the sequence element occurs, and it does not indicate the intended meaning of the data items.

Answer (score 0):

A frequent information/data modeling meaning of an XML `sequence` element is for representing a multi-valued (collection-valued) property of an entity/object type. But then the question is if the ordering of the `sequence` element is significant or if a `sequence` is simply used as a default collection (for avoiding to use `all` for representing an unordered set in XML).